# Creating a hash that is read-only outside of a module, but read/write inside

Tags: hash, immutability, raku

I am creating a module that has some fairly heavily nested hashes.  The hash needs to be semi-regularly modified by the module, which unfortunately rules out using `Map`.

Generally, a branch of the nested hash will be returned to users of the module [1], and the simplest thing to do is to just return that nested hash, e.g.:

```
return %data{$branch}{$subbranch} 
# ↪︎ %(subsubbranch1 => ... , subsubbranch2 => ... )
```

However, the nature of containers like arrays or hashes is that while you can make them read-only, the key/values can still be modified.  The module users though should not actually modify those values for a number of reasons.  Coercing to `Map` won't help, because if any of the values are also containers, they too will be modifiable.

My first thought was to subclass `Hash` (or otherwise make a custom `Associative`), but autovivification by default still goes to Hash.  That, however, can be easily solved by overriding both `AT-KEY` and `ASSIGN-KEY` so that the `AT-KEY` returns an instance of the subclass if the key doesn't already exist:

```
class ProtectedHash is Hash {
    has %!hash = ();
    method EXISTS-KEY ($key)         { %!hash{$key}:exists   }
    method ASSIGN-KEY ($key, \value) { %!hash{$key} = value  }
    method AT-KEY     ($key) {
        %!hash{$key} := ProtectedHash.new unless %!hash{$key}:exists;
        %!hash{$key};
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is to fail if the `ASSIGN-KEY` (or the autovivification part of `AT-KEY`) is called from *outside* my module.  I thought about using something like $?MODULE but that would be set at compile time and always be true.  It looks like I can shimmy off of Backtrace a bit and check for the name of the file that called, but how consistent can I assume the call trace to those two functions?

For example, for `ASSIGN-KEY` I've got:

```
method ASSIGN-KEY ($key, \value) { 
    my @trace = Backtrace.new.list[3..*];
        # The first three can be ignored:
        # 0: code          at ...Backtrace.pm6 
        # 1: method new    at ...Backtrace.pm6
        # 2: method AT-KEY at ...ThisFile.pm6
    if/unless ??? {
        %!hash{$key} = value
    }
}
```

`AT-KEY` is normally called by the sub `postcircumfix<{ }>` (in which case `@trace[0]` can be ignored, and `trace[1]` would be the one of interest) but could also be, albeit rarely, called directly, in which case `trace[0]` is where I'd want to verify the file name.

Are there any other common ways in which `AT-KEY` or `ASSIGN-KEY` might be called?  Or should check those two steps account for 99.9% of calls to those methods? [2]

---

[1] There are only a few subx4 branches that a user might want to manipulate, and so I figure it's best to provide them with the necessarily-slower `.Hash` method for when they really need it than to assume they always need a manipulable container.  At times these may be called enough (particularly via a `get-branch($foo){$subbranch}{$subsubbranch}` pattern), that the addition overhead in creating a deepclone of the Hash becomes decently consequential.
[2] I'm not too concerned about preventing ANY access (although I'm certainly curious if that's possible purely via subclassing), because I'm sure that a fairly industrious coder could always figure something out, but I'd like to catch the most common ones as a way of saying "Can't touch this!" (cue the 90's music…) and provide an [Awesome](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2016/12/23/day-23-everything-is-either-wrong-or-less-than-awesome/) error message.

Comment: I note you haven't accepted an answer. On your answer you've written "The solution I ultimately employed served my needs" which suggests it's acceptable, so I encourage you to accept your answer if it's the best one and solves your problem. Regarding jnthn's answer you note that "role mixing unfortunately doesn't survive binding". But have you read my comment on jnthn's answer? Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 8):

It's probably easier to achieve this by returning something wrapping the original `Array` or `Hash`, or alternatively using `but` to do a shallow copy and mix in to it (which means you retain the original type).

We can declare a role like this:

```
role Can'tTouchThis {
    method AT-KEY(|) {
        untouchable callsame
    }

    method ASSIGN-KEY(|) {
        die "Cannot assign to this";
    }

    method AT-POS(|) {
        untouchable callsame
    }

    method ASSIGN-POS(|) {
        die "Cannot assign to this";
    }
}
```

Where the `sub` `untouchable` is defined as:

```
multi untouchable(Positional \p) {
    p but Can'tTouchThis
}
multi untouchable(Associative \a) {
    a but Can'tTouchThis
}
multi untouchable(\o) {
    o
}
```

Thus handling nested data structures by - on access - creating a read-only facade to those too.

Here's an example and some test cases to illustrate the effect:

```
class Example {
    has %!foo = a => [ 1, 2, [ 3, 4] ], b => { c => { d => 42, e => 19 }, f => 100 };

    method get($sym) {
        untouchable %!foo{$sym}
    }
}

given Example.new {
    use Test;

    # Positional cases
    is .get('a')[0], 1;
    is .get('a')[2][1], 4;
    dies-ok { .get('a')[1] = 42 };
    is .get('a')[1], 2;

    # Associative cases
    is .get('b')<c><d>, 42;
    dies-ok { .get('b')<f> = 99 };
    dies-ok { .get('b')<c><d> = 99 };
    is .get('b')<f>, 100;
    is .get('b')<c><d>, 42;

    # Auto-viv also doesn't work
    dies-ok { .get('a')[4]<a> = 99 };
    dies-ok { .get('a')[4][0] = 99 };
}
```

Remove the `untouchable` call in the `get` method to see the majority of the tests here fail due to lack of protection.

Comment: Ah!  I didn't think of roles for doing it for some reason (and it does go with the idea that roles are generally better than subclasses).  And with the role name `Inmutable`, code is very readable and just makes sense.  Does `but` have fairly low overhead?

Comment: It's not extremely cheap (it reuses the calculated sub-type, which is the big cost, though); you might like to install a cache of the `but`'d objects (can stick it in an attribute of the role). But measure to make sure you need it first. :)

Comment: I've been doing some testing with this and found what might be a fairly common way to use things that gets around this: `%foo = DB.get('foo'); %foo<bar> = 'xyz'` goes without problem.  Based on the docs, the problem is that binding isn't used.  When I change the assignment to `%foo := DB.get('foo')` the failure occurs.

Comment: @guifa You can ensure a variable starts off and remains bound to a `DB` by making the declaration be `my %foo is DB...`. Thereafter *assignment* (with `=`) must adhere to `DB`'s logic and `%foo` can only be *bound* (with `:=`) to a RHS that's another `DB` or one consistent with it (eg a sub-class).

Answer (score 4):

The solution I ultimately employed served my needs, and I'm posting it here for those who may encounter similar situations.  (The answer with role mixing unfortunately doesn't survive binding)

My ultimate approach was to worry the most about unintended editing.  To protect against this, I created an `Associative`-type class called DB-Item that internally has a hash.  The `AT-KEY` method returns the item from the hash if it exists, but `ASSIGN-KEY` and `BIND-KEY` simply immediately fail with an appropriate error message.  The only other method is `ADD-TO-DATABASE`.  That method handles adds leafs/branches depending on what it's passed (and in general end users should be wary of using all caps methods directly).  Since branches can be of different lengths, this also greatly simplifies the initial DB creation:

```perl6
class DB-Item does Associative {

  has %!hash   = ();
  my  $epitaph = "Modification of the database is not a good idea:\n" ~
                 "  - Use .clone if you want to get a editable branch.\n" ~ 
                 "  - If you really know what you're doing, use .ADD-TO-DATABASE";

  method ADD-TO-DATABASE (*@branch) {
    if @branch == 2 {
      %!hash{@branch.head} = @branch.tail
    }else{
      %!hash{@branch.head} = DB-Item.new;
      %!hash{@branch.head}.ADD-TO-DATABASE(@branch[1..*]);
    }
  }

  method ASSIGN-KEY(|) is hidden-from-backtrace { die $epitaph }
  method BIND-KEY(|)   is hidden-from-backtrace { die $epitaph }

  method EXISTS-KEY($key) { %!hash{$key}:exists                        }
  method AT-KEY($key)     { %!hash{$key}:exists ?? %!hash{$key} !! Nil }

  method clone { ... }
}
```